# If the negative and non-negative exponent terms of the Laurent series separately converge inside the annulus, why do we bother adding both together?

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry if this is dense, but I'm still trying to understand the motivation for Laurent series. I feel like I understand the theorems of how to find Laurent series etc., but I don't understand why they're more useful than series that only have positive or negative exponents.

We can split an analytic function $f(z)$ into $f(z) = f_1(z) + f_2(z)$, where $f_1$ is analytic for $|z-z_0|<R_1$, $f_2$ converges for $|z-z_0|>R_2$, and so the region of convergence is $R_2<|z-z_0|<R_1$, which is non-empty if $R_2\le R_1$.

But since $f_1$ and $f_2$ each are individually analytic on the annulus anyway, what's the purpose of adding them together to get a function $f$ that is *only* analytic on the annulus?

Comment: In this situation we are **starting** with the function $f$, not finishing with it. We split $f$ as the sum of $f_1$ and $f_2$, one is represented by a power series in $z-a$ and the other as a power series in $(z-a)^{-1}$ where $a$ is the centre of the annulus.

Comment: Sure, but why can't we just define the Laurent series as the restriction of f1 xor f2 to the annulus, instead of using both?

Comment: Because $f_1+f_2$ equals $f$ on the annulus, but neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ does in general.